Trying to run this sql query on another database but it is returing an error. Database change from T-SQL to MariaDb
A custom report running on a local server here that has MS Sql Server can run this command fine. Im not an expert and this query is probably a bad hodge podge of code, but it worked.
Now the database has been moved into the cloud and an error I get when I have a syntax error trying to figure this out suggests its a MariaDb database.
When I try to run this code that currently works on T-Sql, I get this error:

Parameter index 0 is invalid when only 0 parameters are defined

Here is the query.
/*  Show the CURRENT LOCATIONS of  all the jobs
    Sorted by DueDates first, then by JobNo
*/
Select OrderDet.DueDate, Orders.CustDesc, Orders.PONum,
        CASE
            WHEN OrderDet.QtyOrdered > 0 THEN STR(OrderDet.QtyOrdered)
            WHEN OrderDet.QtyToStock > 0 THEN 'For Stock (' + STR(OrderDet.QtyToStock) +  ')'
        END AS [QTY ORDERED],
        OrderRouting.JobNo, OrderRouting.PartNo,
        CASE
            WHEN OrderRouting.VendCode IS NOT NULL THEN '@ ' + OrderRouting.VendCode
            WHEN StepCount = 1 AND OrderRouting.Status = 'Finished' THEN 'SHIPPING'
            WHEN Online.JobNo IS NOT NULL AND Online.StepNo IS NOT NULL THEN WorkCntr.ShortName /*Display WrkCntr current employee is clocked into*/
            ELSE OrderRouting.WorkCntr
        END AS [Current Location], OrderRouting.OperCode,
        CASE
            WHEN Online.JobNo IS NOT NULL AND Online.StepNo IS NOT NULL THEN 'Clocked In By - ' + Online.EmplCode
            Else ''
        END AS [Current Status],
        CASE
            WHEN OrderDet.JobOnHold = 'Y' THEN 'On Hold'
            WHEN TimeTicketDetails.Comments IS NOT NULL THEN TimeTicketDetails.Comments
            ELSE ''
        END AS [On Hold? / Comments], OrderRouting.StepNo
From OrderRouting
/* Create an intermediate Table for 'StepCount' to be used in main query */
JOIN (  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderRouting.JobNo ORDER BY OrderRouting.StepNo DESC) AS [StepCount], OrderRouting.JobNo, OrderRouting.StepNo
        From OrderRouting
        Where OrderRouting.JobNo IS NOT NULL AND OrderRouting.JobNo != '' ) Step_Count
        ON Step_Count.JobNo = OrderRouting.JobNo AND Step_Count.StepNo = OrderRouting.StepNo
INNER JOIN OrderDet on OrderDet.JobNo = OrderRouting.JobNo
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderNo = OrderRouting.OrderNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN Online ON Online.JobNo = OrderRouting.JobNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN WorkCntr ON WorkCntr.WorkCntr = Online.WorkCntr
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (
                    Select TimeTicketDet.* From TimeTicketDet
                    JOIN  (
                            Select JobNo, StepNo, MAX(TimeTicketDet_ID) as [LastID] From TimeTicketDet
                            GROUP BY JobNo, StepNo
                        ) tt1 ON tt1.JobNo = TimeTicketDet.JobNo AND tt1.LastID = TimeTicketDet.TimeTicketDet_ID
                ) TimeTicketDetails ON TimeTicketDetails.JobNo = OrderRouting.JobNo AND TimeTicketDetails.StepNo = OrderRouting.StepNo
WHERE   OrderDet.Status = 'Open' AND
        (OrderRouting.Status = 'Current'  OR (OrderRouting.Status = 'Finished' AND Step_Count.StepCount = 1))
Order By    DueDate,
            OrderRouting.OrderNo,
            OrderRouting.JobNo,
            OrderRouting.StepNo

Any ideas what is causing this error?
Thanks.

I think the question mark in [[On Hold? / Comments]] might be interpreted as a parameter place holder? You are using square brackets as a quote character for column names with special characters; MariaDB doc says back-quote or double-quote is to be used

MySQL and MariaDB use backticks where T-SQL uses square brackets.

There are lots of other differences between SQL-Server and MariaDB.

There are more errors now, but fixing the ? got me past this one error that was driving me nuts. Thank you.

Check the compatibility options in MariaDB.

I think the question mark in [On Hold? / Comments] might be interpreted as a parameter place holder? You are using square brackets as a quote character for column names with special characters; MariaDB doc says back-quote or double-quote is to be used ; see:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/
